# Azure AD B2C Reply URL

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a web app on Azure AD B2C using the [Dot Net Web App and Web API sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi).

I have modified it slightly as I need the Reply URL to return to an application under an IIS website.
i.e. `https://xxx.dev.xx/mysite`

What seems to happen is once the user has registered or logged in, AD does redirect back to `https://xxx.dev.xx/mysite` but the user is not authenticated.

**Update**
Sorry I should have said that if I change my site in IIS to  https://xxx.dev.xx/ and have the reply Url the same then it works perfectly.

The **mysite** is an application under a website called **xxx.dev.xx**.

I have not changed any code from the sample app, so in the Index.cshtml there is a check of Request.IsAuthenticated to toggle the **login/log** out link.
I will try and post some screen shots

Comment: Please provide more details so that people can help you. Using Chrome's developer tools (F12), check out the request/responses between you app and B2C. Also include screenshots of how you've configured your app in the B2C portal and whatever else you think is relevant.

Comment: How is your IIS website/app checking and verifying the redirect from Azure? Are you verifying the id_token and it's claims? Or are you saying that azure is not passing that to your application at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the home folder path to the end of the reply url like this:

https://primary.domain.com/applicationname/home

I had a similar problem once and this solved it for me.

Paul

Comment: Thanks this seemed to cure my issue too